# How can read SQLite query result in java

Tags: java, android

How can read the following result in java?

I would like your help.

```
Strint query = select case when exists (select * from [entry] where title='Hanim') then cast (1 as bit) else cast (0 as bit) end
Cursor cursor = mdb.rawQuery(query,null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(query));
```

Comment: cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(0)); //0 for first column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String query="select case when exists 
(select * from [entry] 
where title='Hanim') 
then cast (1 as bit) else cast (0 as bit) end
as [result]"
Cursor cursor=mdb.rawQuery(query,null);
int cIX=cursor.getColumnIndex("result");
data=cursor.getString(cIX);
```

if we dont add a beer we can not read with java.
for this reason the as [result] was added to the title.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
 do{
  String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data"));
 .
 .              // do something you need
 }while(cursor.moveToNext());
 }
   cursor.close();
```